# Getting the syntax right for MySQL select with inner join

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

Using MySQL version 5.1.73 and phpmyadmin 4.0.10.16.

I am unable to get this past the syntax checker:

```
select * from courses as co , course_type as ct 
left join course_leaders as cl on cl.course_leaders_id = co.course_leaders_id1
left join course_links_to_innstyle as cli on cli.course_links_to_innstyle_id = co.course_links_to_innstyle_id 
where co.course_type_id = ct.course_type_id
order by short,start_date ASC
```

It insists that there is no column "co.course_leaders_id1" which there is indeed.

Any ideas anyone?

ok, this is the result I came up (with the help from below - thanks)

```
select * from courses as co
left join course_leaders as cl on cl.course_leaders_id = co.course_leaders_id1
left join course_links_to_innstyle as cli on cli.course_links_to_innstyle_id = co.course_links_to_innstyle_id 
inner join course_type as ct on co.course_type_id = ct.course_type_id
order by short,start_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **problem one** is that you are mixing explicit (SQL-92) `JOIN` syntax with implicit join, `,` (SQL-89) comma syntax. While this is allowed and with some care it may even work correctly, it's very easy to get this type of errors.

The `FROM` part of your query:

```
from courses as co , course_type as ct 
left join course_leaders as cl 
    on cl.course_leaders_id = co.course_leaders_id1
left join course_links_to_innstyle as cli 
    on cli.course_links_to_innstyle_id = co.course_links_to_innstyle_id
```

is parsed as:

```
from 
    courses as co 
  ,                        -- <-- that acts as a CROSS JOIN
    (
        (
            course_type as ct 
        left join 
            course_leaders as cl 
        on 
            cl.course_leaders_id = co.course_leaders_id1
        )
    left join 
        course_links_to_innstyle as cli 
    on 
        cli.course_links_to_innstyle_id = co.course_links_to_innstyle_id 
    )
```

Now it's clear that inside the parentheses, `co` is not defined.

---

**Problem two** is that there is no joining condition for `ct`. You have 4 tables but only 2 (and not 3) joining conditions. This is either something you missed or the intention of the query is to do a `CROSS JOIN`.

---

**Solution**:

- It's better to use explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere and not mix the two (syntaxes).
- Fix the code by either adding the missing condition or use `CROSS JOIN` if that is the intention of the query.